# About Android keyboard Library issue

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I am working on keyboard and using `android 3.3`, before `3.3 version`, there was no problem in my keyboard code, but when i update android to `3.3` now this one problem occurs.

```
   configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                    if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                        details.useVersion '25.3.1'
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

this `DependencyResolveDetails` statement is red, i dont know why. please i need help.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: most probably due to gradle sync error

Comment: Error is only shows in gradle this DependencyResolveDetails  in red color and when i rebuild it, it shows same, i don't know why?

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xpertkeyboards.android.inputmethod.latin.photo.emoji.theme.typing.english.malaysiankeyboard.malaykeyboard"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android_sound.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'

Comment: // emoji Liabrary
    implementation project(':emoji')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

Comment: // Liabraries

    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:2.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

Comment: testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

Comment: configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.1'
                }
            }

        }
    }

Comment: @M.Yousaf you can edit your question and add `build.gradle` there and not via comments

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I closed the project. Removed the project from open recent projects menu and re-opened the project newly and not from open recent.

Comment: Sir i did the same like you, but still error occured

Comment: hi, i just remove DependencyResolveDetails , and soved it, thanks every one